# Format Exception reading a File in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file that has many lines with patient's info like this:

```
72514202,John,Schwimmer,h,60,65,166,68,126,69,n,68
```

I have set up the following code in the main method:

```
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("File001.txt"));

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] temp = line.split(",");

        int doc = Integer.valueOf(temp[0]); //id 
        String name = temp[1]; //name
        //other data set,
    }
```

My problem is, I have checked that the file is in the same folder as the java program and that it is properly named, yet I'm getting this exception for what would be temp[0], the first person's ID

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
at Principal.main(Principal.java:49)
```

why could I be getting this exception? why is it not reading the file properly?

Comment: What java version are you using? Depending on Java version temp[0] could either be an empty string or contains the ID.

Comment: I'm using java11

Comment: @Mar Go through the debugger and see if  the temp String array is not actually empty. You may not read the file properly etc.

Comment: Oh then that is probably not your issue. Try printing array or use debugge like @BorisBorovski mentioned.

Comment: I will try! thanks